# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape_string() on null

Tags: php, sql

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape_string() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\url\classes\shortener.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\url\shorten.php(10): Shortener->makeCode('stackove...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\url\classes\shortener.php on line 19

i am designing my own url shortener but it gave me this error when i tested it.
The code i am using for this

This is the shorten file to get the input url
shorten.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'classes/shortener.php';

$s = new Shortener;

if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $url = $_POST['url'];

    if($code = $s->makeCode($url)) {
        echo $code;
    } else {

    }

 }
```

this is the file which shortens the url
shortener.php

```
<?php
class Shortener{
    protected $db;

    public function _construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','shortenedurl');
    }

     protected function generateCode($num){
        return base_convert($num, 10, 36);
     } 

     public function makeCode($url){
        $url = trim($url);

        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            return '';
        }
        $url = $this->db->escape_string($url);

        $exists = $this->db->query("SELECT code FROM short_urls WHERE urlinput = '{$url}'");

        if($exists->num_rows)  {
            return $exists->fetch_object()->code;
        } else {
            $insert = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO short_urls(urlinput, created) VALUES ('{$url}', NOW())");

            $code = $this->generateCode($this->db->insert_id);

            $this->db->query("UPDATE short_urls SET code ='{$code}' WHERE url ='{$url}'");

            return $code;    
        }
    }

    public function getUrl($code){
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup! So what is your question?

Comment: why am i getting this error..

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape_string() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\url\classes\shortener.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\url\shorten.php(10): Shortener->makeCode('http://stackove...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\url\classes\shortener.php on line 19

Comment: Would have been useful to put that in your question. I have done that for you this time

Comment: Obviously `$this->db` is `null` so it's not setting up the database connection. Do some kind of logging and error-checking, then you'll see the reason.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear to me. `$this->db` is `null`

Comment: I would guess your connection to the database has failed. You dont actually test that it has worked

Comment: i've checked...it is connected to the database...all the details are correct

Answer (score 1):

The construct need to start with two of '_' so it must be '__' .
So you need to change `public function _construct(){` to this `public function __construct(){`